# Tesseract OCR produces empty results

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I need to extract digits from images (see sample images). I tried `pytesseract` but it is not working, it produces empty results. Below is the code I am using

**Code**

```
import pytesseract
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('image_path')
digits = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(digits)
```

**Sample Images**

[image]

[image]

I have a large pool of images, as shown above. `Tesseract` is not working on any of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding config `--psm 7` (meaning `Treat the image as a single text line.`)

```
import pytesseract
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('image_path')
digits = pytesseract.image_to_string(img,config='--psm 7')
print(digits)
#'971101004900 1545'
```

Comment: You are the saviour